# create ListView.Bulder from true bools in a list. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list called MyList which takes a unique class called . in MyItem class, there is a String and a bool.

I have a ListView.Builder and I want it to create a list of tiles from MyList but i only want it to create tiles for where the bool in MyItem is true.

what is the syntax needed to do this please?

thanks so much

Comment: As in, in the item count of the listView.Builder. something .length. how do i just pulled out the items in the list with a true bool?

Answer (score 1):

You can either filter the list like`final myFilteredList = myList.where((myItem) => myItem.myBool)`, or inside the builder, depending on the bool value just return a `SizedBox.shrink()`.